# How to force gcc use int for system calls, not sysenter?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, system-calls

Is it possible to force gcc use *int* instruction for all the system calls, but not *sysenter*? This question may sound strange but I have to compile some projects like Python and Firefox this way.

**Summary**

Thanks to jbcreix, I've downloaded glibc 2.9 source code, and modified the lines in sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h, to disable use of sysenter by `#undef I386_USE_SYSENTER`, and it works.

Comment: easy, recompile your C library after replacing sysenter by int 80 in syscall.s and link again. This is not compiler generated code which means you are lucky.

Comment: @jbcreix Thanks for that. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recompile your C library after replacing `sysenter` by `int 0x80` in `syscall.s` and link again.

This is not compiler generated code which means you are lucky.

The ultimate origin of the actual syscall is here, as the OP says:

http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/libc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h?root=libc&view=markup

And as I suspected there really was a syscall.S it's just that the glibc sources are a labyrinth.

http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/libc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/syscall.S?root=libc&view=markup

So I think he got it right, asveikau.

Comment: I thought that these days the "int 80h" or "sysenter" comes from linux-gate.so which is mapped to a magic page by the kernel.  At least on x86.

Answer (score 2):

You don't modify gcc; you modify libc (or more accurately, recompile it) and the kernel. gcc doesn't emit sysenter instructions; it generates calls to the generic syscall(2) interface, which presents a unified front end to system call entry and exit.

Or, you could use a Pentium; SYSENTER wasn't introduced until PII =]. Note the following KernelTrap link for the interesting methods used by Linux: http://kerneltrap.org/node/531